# How to hide a content of a file?

Tags: files, vim, encryption

Is there any way to hide the content of a file?
Suppose I have the file bind which contains the following line:

```
This is a test.
```

After saving the file, it should not display its content.

Is there a way to do this in Linux?

Comment: What do you mean by “it should not display its content”? Why not remove the content from the file? If the content is “hidden”, how would you reveal it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `vim` command `:X` to encrypt the file.

It will prompt you for an encryption key, twice.  Then save the file as normal.  If someone tries to read the file (including [root](/questions/tagged/root) user), it will be gibberish:

```
Mark@MarkBeast ~
$ vim test.txt

Mark@MarkBeast ~
$ cat test.txt
VimCrypt~01!o▒rl▒_▒Ĩ7vE=▒g
Mark@MarkBeast ~
$
```

When you vim the file later, it will prompt you for the key.

```
Need encryption key for "test.txt"
Enter encryption key:

This is a test
~
~
~ 
"test.txt" [crypted] 2 lines, 16 characters
```

Comment: where the key is saving? maybe within file itself? so it's can be readable?

Comment: 2nd, this encryption is valid out of the box?

Comment: Not sure where the key is kept, but must be in the file itself so it is self-contained in case you move the file elsewhere.  It is standard option, I think even `vi` supports it.

Comment: Just tested again; and the key is kept in the file.  The size of the file (at least a small file) grows a bit to add the `VimCrypt` magic text and what I assume is the hash of the key.  And my prior comment about `vi` support is wrong; this is only in `vim` and also the clarify the `:X` command is an upper-case `x` and you invoke it before you save the file; when you invoke the command it will prompt you for the encryption key.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permissions on the file to 000.

```
$ chmod 000 somefile
```

#### Example

*Initially we have this file:*

```
$ cat afile 
secret
```

*Change the permissions, and confirm:*

```
$ chmod 000 afile

$ ls -l afile 
----------. 1 slm slm 7 Nov 26 13:07 afile
```

*Now we can't see it:*

```
$ cat afile 
cat: afile: Permission denied
```

#### Caveats with this

1. This is easy to bypass if the user is either root or the owner of the file.
2. You cannot write to this file while the permissions are 000.

   ```
   $ echo "another secret" >> afile
   bash: afile: Permission denied
   ```

Comment: if a normal user uses this method he/she can hide content from all users except root, not good method

Comment: this solution is easy reversible unfortunately and another thing is that actually you [user here I mean] are defrauding yourself!

Comment: @αғsнιη - yup I even stated that in the caveats section. Regarding the defrauding comment I don't understand what this means.

Comment: I meant, it's like a thing that user is locking something while the key is in everyone's hand, so in my opinion this answer is less valuable.

Comment: @αғsнιη - understood. That's a fair critique.

Answer (score -1):

I usually do this.

```
sudo chmod 000 file && sudo chflags uchg file
```

Technically it won't "hide" the contents but its a good way to keep it out of public access. Might wan't to `chflags hidden file` on it too, which will hide it.

Comment: `chflags` appears to be a FreeBSD command but https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/tag/chflags-command says that linux `chattr +i filename` command